# JavaFX InputMismatchException - Label from Scanner

Tags: java, javafx, label, java.util.scanner, vbox

problems will be there cause i want make Labels from text file and then put it into VBOX and i getting inputmismatchexception and it dont make new Object

```
VBox vertikalBox = new VBox();
try (Scanner s = new Scanner("rebricek.txt")) {
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            //InputMismatchException 
            vertikalBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label(""+ s.nextInt() + " " + s.next() + " " + s.nextInt()));
            s.nextLine();
        }


    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // inputmismatchexception - PROBLEM
        // this is for NoSuchElementException
        System.err.println("Vyskytla sa chyba pri praci zo suborom");
    }
```

FILE content :

```
1 nikto 10
2 nikto 0
3 nikto 0
4 nikto 0
5 nikto 0
6 nikto 0
7 nikto 0
8 nikto 0
9 nikto 0
10 nikto 0
```

Comment: Replace nextInt with next.

Comment: Also getChildren().addAll() can be getChildren.add().

Comment: next() no helps problem is in Text file somehow Scanner cant read it :( and idk why   it telling me it has not Line on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scanner is reading the string "rebrickek.txt" not a file

```
File file = new File("rebricek.txt");

if(file.exist())
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    .
    .
    .
}
else
{
    System.out.println("The file does note exist!");
}
```

Comment: och xD IntelliJ was telling me its source xD so i decided its File Path 
(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("rebricek.txt")))  works :)